# Cloud Endpoints Extensible Service Proxy not honouring security definition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

We are using the ESP inside the container engine (not as part of appengine).  We have deployed the following swagger file:

```
security:
 - oauth_our_oauth:
   - default_auth
# This section requires all requests to any path to require an API key.
securityDefinitions:
 oauth_our_oauth:
     authorizationUrl: "https://OUR_ACCOUNT.auth0.com/authorize"
     flow: "implicit"
     type: "oauth2"
     x-issuer: "https://OUR_ACCOUNT.auth0.com/"
     # Update this with your service account's email address.
     x-jwks_uri: "https://OUR_ACCOUNT.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json"
     scopes:
       default_auth: All endpoints
```

However when we hit our endpoint without any authentication the request happily passes through.  Are we setting up something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth definition should be referenced in x-security section.

```
x-security:
  - oauth_our_oauth:
      audiences:
      # This must match the "aud" field in the JWT. You can add multiple
      # audiences to accept JWTs from multiple clients.
      - "echo.endpoints.sample.google.com"
```

Example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/flexible/endpoints/swagger.yaml

Comment: Mingliang - Is this documented anywhere? Why do we have specify audiences as opposed to what the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/authenticating-users outlines? Is the regular security and scopes not supported by the ESP?

Comment: We have tried this but we are receiving this error: {
"code": 16,
"message": "JWT validation failed: Issuer not allowed",
"details": [
 {
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
  "stackEntries": [],
  "detail": "auth"
 }
]
}?

Comment: Endpoints V2 makes sure the audiences in the JWT is either the host name defined in the swagger config, or is in the list of audiences you've provided in the x-security section.

At this point we do not have any checks on scopes. We would like to hear about your use case and requirements.

Comment: The "issuer not allowed" could happen in two cases -

1. The JWT token issuer that your API receives does not match the issuer in the swagger config. You may use jwt.io to decode the JWT.

2. For some reason you have an out of sync temp config file locally. Note the temp config file I mentioned here was generated from the swagger config file. To fix this problem, you may remove the temp file, or recheck out the samples, and then redeploy your app.